# Setup NetBeans for Zend Framework2

Tags: netbeans, zend-framework2

I have been trying to find of how to setup my NetBeans for Zend Framework 2. I found loads of materials for previous versions of Zend Framework i.e Zend Framework 1... and so but not for Zend Framework 2. In case if somebody has a solution would be great if it can be shared.

P.S There is no zf.bat file which is what normally the tutorials say to include path for zf.bat in netbeans.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: solved it myself by adding the zend framework2 library in Netbeans.

Comment: Did my comment help you at all? Are you able to get Code completion working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Zend framework reaches some sort of release candidate or some final release I wouldn't expect there to be a zf.bat file yet.

The structure of an application has been somewhat established by the Skeleton Application available on github but I wouldn't expect a zf file until the final release.

The zf would setup a standard project structure. Although the skeleton app exists this structure isn't 100% yet.

Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if we started to use Composer or Git as a way of pulling the skeleton off of the internet, but I doubt that will happen.

Anyway, the zf file is useful at first but afterwards it becomes more of a hassle. It's useful but not TOO much once you know your way around the structure. Additionally Zend would have to rework it to work with the whole module idea.

BUT, if you just want some IDE code complete help all you really have to do is add the Zend library to your project's path and have Netbeans help you with that.

Comment: thanks for your post, unfortunately I did not do the way you have suggested, but included the Zend Library in Netbeans Global Include Path and it works for me

Comment: That's what I said, "BUT, if you just want some IDE code complete help all you really have to do is add the Zend library to your project's path and have Netbeans help you with that."

Comment: got it now anyway thanks for your reply and Im accepting your answer